# Mac mission control add new space + icon is on left - not the right

Tags: macos, catalina, mission-control, big-sur

How can I fix this?

[image]

I don't recall changing a setting for this, but I really wish it was on the right as per normal (was like this prior to Big Sur update as well.)

Normal is right I assume - much better!

https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204100

Comment: Seems to be because I have my dock on the right hand side ...

Comment: Interesting behavior, any chance you would be willing to rewrite your comment into an answer? You can then mark your answer as accepted so that your question appears as solved, which will help others with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the dock on the right hand side causes this (unwanted) change. Hoping to find a terminal command to fix this be still unsure why Apple feels this is necessary.